# pandas to_datetime but replace with fixed value when fail/coerce, preserve 'meaningful' NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

When using `pd.to_datetime` on my data frame I get this error:

```
Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 30-04-18 00:00:00
```

Now from looking on StackO I know I can simply use the `coerce` option:

```
pd.to_datetime('13000101', format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```

But I was wondering if anyone had an idea on how I might replace these values with a fixed value? Say `1900-01-01 00:00:00` (or maybe 1955-11-12 for anyone who gets the reference!)

Reason being that this data frame is part of a process that handles thousands and thousands of JSONs per day. I want to be able to see in the dataset easily the incorrect ones by filtering for said fixed date.

It is just as invalid for the JSON to contain any date before 2010 so using an earlier date is fine and **it is also perfectly acceptable to have a blank (NA) date value so I can't rely on just blanking the data**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace missing values by some default datetime value in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) only for missing values generated by `to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"date": [np.nan,'20180101','20-20-0']})

t = pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')
date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')

df['date'] = date.mask(date.isna() & df['date'].notna(), t)
print (df)
        date
0        NaT
1 2018-01-01
2 1900-01-01
```

Comment: I did think this but I can't fill all missing values as some could be actually missing from the dataset and I have to have those remain blank.

Comment: What's wrong with simply `df['date'] = df['date'].fillna(t)` ? Oh I see, 'meaningful' NAs already present in 'date' column should be left as NA.